# How to resize TouchableOpacity according to the component present inside it?

Tags: javascript, react-native, touchableopacity

I'm using `TouchableOpacity` to make a button as I'm learning react-native.

But the problem is, `TouchableOpacity` takes 100% width of the screen. But, I want to take the size/grow with the component present inside it.

How can I do it?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
export default class App extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
        <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => console.log("Pressed!")}
            style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}
        >

            <Text>Press me!</Text>

        </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }
```

When I decrease the width of the `TouchableOpacity` like 10 or 20, it automatically increases its height to fit the `Text`.

So, it possible for `TouchableOpacity` to grow with the size of component present inside it?

Comment: With your current code snipper, the TouchableOpacity should already wrap around the Text and grow with it in size. Are you sure you aren't setting `flex : 1` on a parent component?

Comment: @patngo My bad. Indeed I'm using `flex: 1` in `TouchableOpacity`. I thought I deleted the `style` prop but I missed it. Thanks for pointing out. Now it works.

Comment: FWIW I've added "flex: 0" to the TouchableOpacity's style directly and still having this problem, in case anybody has any ideas...

Answer (score 13):

You can actually use alignSelf: 'flex-start' or 'flex-end' depending on which side you want to pin